# How to store a js value in php variable?

Tags: javascript, php

I want to store the value of x in js variable into php variable on the same page.

Comment: why ? you want to store client side input to server side. you can store js value into hidden input and then you can use it in php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming) <- When reading that post, remember that Javascript is client side and PHP is server side.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is: you can not.

The reason for this: PHP is executed on the server side, and the response is sent to the browser, and (usually) generated as HTML. The javascript is rendered *after* this, so at this point, the PHP code no longer exists.

Long answer:

You can send a javascript variable to PHP using an XHR request (or more commonly known as an AJAX call). This will be a different request from the one that loads your initial page though. For more information see this: https://www.w3schools.com/Php/php_ajax_php.asp

Comment: Many dupes. Please find one and vote to close instead of answering

Answer (score 0):

you can use ajax or
add input hidden with this value and when submit form sent a value

i think in most cast ajax in best.

$.ajax({
      url: 'url',
      method: 'POST',

```
  data: 'data',
  cache: false,
       success:function(data){

  },
  error: function(data){

  }
}); // end ajax
```